# Integration: differential brackets confusion

Tags: integration, brownian-motion

In one of the elementary books for stochastic calculus, author didn't clearly explain the difference between $\int(dW_s)^2$ and $\int d(W_s)^2$, using both in the explanations.

**Could you please briefly point out the difference between $\int(dW_s)^2$ and $\int d(W_s)^2$?**

As I see it: one is squared difference in process , another is difference in squared process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(dW_s)^2$ does not really make proper sense, but in view of Ito's formula (among some other things) it can be understood as just the same as $ds$. $d(W_s)^2$ means "integration against the process $W_s^2$". You might perhaps understand it as $d(W_s^2-s)+ds$, in which case that first term is now integration against a martingale (which is relatively well-understood).

In terms of Riemann sum approximations your intuition is correct, in an integral with $(dW_s)^2$ you would have $(\Delta W)^2$ in the sum approximations, while in an integral with $d(W_s^2)$ you would have $\Delta(W^2)$ in the sum approximations.

Comment: "understood as just the same as $ds$". Do you mean $\int(dW_s)^2ds$?

Comment: @CronAcronis No, I mean that $\int f \: (dW_s)^2 = \int f ds$, to the extent that the left side makes sense at all.

Comment: Could you please explain it? It is not clear for me.

Comment: @CronAcronis To understand it properly, you should try to compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(i/n) (W((i+1)/n)-W(i/n))^2$. You should find that it is the same as $\int_0^1 f(t) dt$.